# Angular charts using json data and KendoUI

Tags: json, angular, charts, kendo-ui, httpclient

I'm a beginner and i tried to create a pie chart using json data. but this code does not shows any error and it does not show the chart also.

**component.ts file** is here

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  export class pieData {
  constructor(
    public kind: string,
    public share: number,
  ) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pie-chart',
  templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie-chart.component.css']
})
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {

  pieData: pieData[];
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
      ngOnInit() {
    this.getpieData();
  }
      getpieData() {
    this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/pieData').subscribe(
      Response => {
        console.log(Response);
        this.pieData = Response;
      }
    );

    console.log(this.pieData);
  }
}
```

**component.html file** is here

```
    <kendo-chart [transitions]="false" [style.height]="'100%'" [style.width]="'100%'">
  <kendo-chart-tooltip format='{0}%'></kendo-chart-tooltip>
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="pie"
                             categoryField="kind"
                             field="share"
                             [autoFit]="true"
                             *ngIf="pieData">
      <kendo-chart-series-item-labels [align]="labelAlign"
                                      color="#000"
                                      [content]="labelContent">
      </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
  <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="false"></kendo-chart-legend>
</kendo-chart>
```

**db.json** file is here (it is inside the assets folder)

```
 "pieData": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "kind": "Solar",
      "share": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "kind": "Wind",
      "share": 2
    },
   ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should modify `getData()` method to get your data from the json file

```js
getpieData() {
    this.httpClient.get('assets/db.json').subscribe(
      Response => {
        this.pieData = Response;
      }
    );
```

Then you can pass this data to your chart using `[data]` attribute

```html
<kendo-chart [transitions]="false" [style.height]="'100%'" [style.width]="'100%'">
  <kendo-chart-tooltip format='{0}%'></kendo-chart-tooltip>
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="pie"
                             [data]="pieData?.pieData"
                             categoryField="kind"
                             field="share"
                             [autoFit]="true"
                             *ngIf="pieData">
      <kendo-chart-series-item-labels [align]="labelAlign"
                                      color="#000"
                                      [content]="labelContent">
      </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
  <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="false"></kendo-chart-legend>
</kendo-chart>
```

Here is a working example:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-local-data-zvrhxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: it also does not show any error and do not show the graph. when we creating graphs is it mandatory to create service file?

Comment: try to use `pieData: null` instead of `pieData: pieData[]` with the same code of my answer and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: I want to create json file inside the asset folder and get those data to create chart

Comment: no problem, I have updated the link I mentioned in my answer, please check it.